# How to use QVideoSink to get frames from QMediaPlayer in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qmediaplayer

QVideoSink is a new class in Qt 6.3, and therefore not much information or examples for it are available regarding how to use it. Myself being a beginner with Qt am finding it difficult to understand how to use it.
It would be great if someone could go ahead and give a simple working example of using QVideoSink for getting frames with QMediaPlayer.
Here is the documentation: [QVideoSink](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvideosink.html)

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73568982/qt-getting-a-thumbnail-for-a-video

Comment: @Alexander The question is legit. At the moment of writing the question, the Qt documentation for QtMultimedia was not complete, for example https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaplayer.html does not contain any mention of `videoSink()`. In fact it does not contain it now, it may be updated in the future. On the other hand this doc contains the info https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qmediaplayer.html